# SQL table with 70 plus columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm designing a database table for a manufacturing company, amongst the tables required is a part applications table (meaning this product applies to x and y product), my current issue is that most product lines have about 3 to 10 applications, but 2 specific lines have up to 100 applications.

At first I thought about storing product applications as a comma separated string, but that would violate the first normal form.

Then I read about storing said applications as a blob, however in the interest of both search optimization and general DB performance this doesn't seem to be a possibility.

My question is this, is there a way to store part applications in a table without having to create the 70+ columns, while mantaining normal forms and not compromising performance??

Comment: A BLOB does just as much violence, if not more, than storing the applications as CSV list.  Listen to the answers below... you want to create a many-to-many bridge table that links `Products` & `PartApplications`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a Look-up table and a many-to-many bridge table.

3rd normal form is usually good. create a table for associated applications. Store a reference ID that is a constraint to whatever other table you were thinking about including this data in.

Answer (score 4):

To satisfy `not compromising performance` requires knowing exactly what queries you will be running.

But in normal cases like these you'd have a many:many mapping table...

```
CREATE TABLE map_part_application (
  part_id         INT,
  application_id  INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (part_id, application_id)
)


INSERT INTO map_part_application VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO map_part_application VALUES (1,2)
...
INSERT INTO map_part_application VALUES (1,100)
INSERT INTO map_part_application VALUES (2,1)
INSERT INTO map_part_application VALUES (2,2)
...
INSERT INTO map_part_application VALUES (1,12)
```

I would recommend going this way as standard practice, and only looking elsewhere should you find you need to optimise later in the build.

Comment: Thanks, this is definetely the way to go, the part of not compromising performance exists because there will be a lot of searches for particular applications of each part (e.g.: Client comes in and asks "does this work for my bike?")

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a table for product line with a fk to your product table?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to store the part applications as separate rows, not columns in the same row.

If you have only part applications in the table, just make several rows instead of several columns in the row.

If you have other data in the table also, make another table just for connecting that data to several part applications.